# Javascript settimeouts on html whack a mole game

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, settimeout

I've been trying to create a html whack a mole game in which a mole has a class added to it at a certain interval, another timeout function is then triggered giving the user 3 seconds to click the mole and remove the class before a check is carried out which determines if that mole still has the class attached to it.

here is a jsfiddle of my game : https://jsfiddle.net/gko9puqf/1/ and below is my javascript.

```
var score = 0;
var numberofpipes = 9;
var lastnum = 0;
var intervalseconds;
var interval;
var haslost = false;
var checkpipetimer;
var timeoutfunc;
var timeoutinit;
var timers = [];
var burstingpipes = {};
var timeoutinit = setTimeout(startaburst, 3000);
$('#scorecontainer').text(score);
//starts a bursting pipe
function startaburst() {
  clearTimeout(timeoutinit);
  if (score < 10) {
    intervalseconds = 2;
  } else if (score >= 10 && score < 25) {
    intervalseconds = 1.5;
  } else if (score >= 25 && score < 40) {
    intervalseconds = 1;
  } else if (score >= 40 && score < 60) {
    intervalseconds = 0.5;
  } else if (score >= 60) {
    intervalseconds = 0.25;
  } else if (score > 100) {
    intervalseconds = 0.1;
  }
  interval = intervalseconds * 1000;
  burstingpipe();
  //creating a loop with the new timeout value as the game gets harder.
  //also assigning it to the timeoutfunc variable so i can cancel the loop later.
  timeoutfunc = setTimeout(startaburst, interval);
}

//adds the bursting pipe attributes to the pipe intersections
function burstingpipe() {
  randomnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;
  //cant be the same twice in case of overlapping
  if ((randomnum == lastnum) || $("." + randomnum).hasClass("burstingpipe")) {
    //if the random num is still valid after -1, -1
    if (((randomnum - 1) >= 0) && !($("." + (randomnum - 1)).hasClass("burstingpipe"))) {
      randomnum = (randomnum - 1);
      //add one to the random number
    } else if (((randomnum + 1) <= (numberofpipes)) && !($("." + (randomnum + 1)).hasClass("burstingpipe"))) {
      randomnum = (randomnum + 1);
    } else {
      burstingpipe();
    }
  }
  //make the lastnum the current number so we dont get 2 in a row
  lastnum = randomnum;
  randomdiv = $("." + randomnum);
  console.log(randomdiv.hasClass("burstingpipe"));
  //adds shake animation and red glow
  console.log(randomnum);
  randomdiv.addClass("burstingpipe");

  //setting a timeout of 3 seconds, so th user has 3 seconds to press each 
  //bursting pipe before it bursts.
  checkpipetimer = setTimeout(haspipeburst.bind(this, randomdiv), 3000);
}

//function to check if the pipe has burst.
function haspipeburst(pipecheck) {
  console.log(pipecheck);
  console.log(pipecheck.hasClass("burstingpipe"));
  //checking to see if the pipe still has the class attached after 3 seconds
  //and if the user has already lost.
  if (pipecheck.hasClass("burstingpipe")) {
    //if the pipe still has the class attached - game over.
    haslost = true;
    $("#result").text("you have lost");
    //stopping the loop.
    clearTimeout(timeoutfunc);
    //changing the background color to make it look like the pipe has broken.
    //(will possibly change to image in future)
    //$(".hitpoint").removeClass("burstingpipe");
    $(pipecheck).css("background-color", "#49c1e2");
  }
}

//when the user clicks a hitpoint the class is removed and they gain a point.
$(document).on('click', '.hitpoint', function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("burstingpipe") && haslost == false) {
    $(this).removeClass("burstingpipe");
    score++;
    $("#scorecontainer").text(score);
  }
});
```

it works as expected up until the timeout gets significantly shorter (around a score of 40) and the moles glitch out as if the timeout was ignored.

I've been staring at the code for hours now and have made little progress so I am hoping you can help me out! i believe its something to do with the timeouts not being completed properly.

any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `settimeout` isn't buggy the way you have used it would be buggy

Comment: yes agreed sorry, this is my first post on stack overflow, I do mean the way i'm using them, there is obviously a flaw somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit of a late addition, but was working a bit on this in-between other tasks. As stated a problem with starting multiple timers is that you need to remember the specific timers and not only the last one. In the code below that is done by keeping a 'bursting pipe' inside a single class (function) with its own timer.

Perhaps I went a bit overboard, but as also stated by others, I liked the game you made :) One of the changes is not looping through all pipes to get a pipes that's not bursting, but remove the pipe from available pipes once it's bursting. This also negates the need for numbering the divs. More details in the code-comments. Of course you're free to ignore this code completely, but since I had it about finished, am posting it anyway.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gko9puqf/4/)

```js
var score = 24; //set higher for testing purposes
var pipes = $('.hitpoint').toArray() ,
 last = null,
  haslost = false,
 interval = 2, //start interval
 thresholds = {10: 1.5, 25: 1 , 40: 0.5, 60:0.25, 100 :1}; //interval thresholds
setTimeout(startaburst, 3000); //intial timeout (doesn't need to be cleared, because it's fired once)

$('#scorecontainer').text(score);
//starts a bursting pipe
function startaburst() {
 if(haslost)return; //already lost
  
  if(pipes.length>0){ //pick a pipe to burst unless all pipes allready bursting
    var i;
    while(true){
      var p = pipes[i = Math.floor(Math.random() * pipes.length)]; //get random element from the available pipes
      if(p!==last || pipes.length === 1)break;
    }  
    pipes.splice(i,1); //remove pipe from available pipes
    last = p; //remember last to prevent reusing the same pipe twice
    new burstingPipe(p);
 }
  
  setTimeout(startaburst, interval * 1000); //wait until staring the new burst. interval is increased inside backInGame if the score increases
}

function burstingPipe(pipe){
 this.pipe = $(pipe);
  this.pipe.addClass("burstingpipe");  
  
  function checkBurst(){  
   this.dispose();
   if(haslost)return; //already lost on other pipe
    haslost = true;
    $("#result").text("you have lost");
    //changing the background color to make it look like the pipe has broken.
    //(will possibly change to image in future)      
    this.pipe.css("background-color", "#49c1e2");
  };
  
  this.dispose=function(){
   this.pipe.off('click'); //unbind click (no longer bursting or already burst)
   this.pipe.removeClass("burstingpipe");    
  }
  
  function backInGame(){   
   clearTimeout(this.timer); //clear the burst timeout (specific for this pipe)
    this.dispose();
    pipes.push(this.pipe[0]); //make pipe available again (NB, because the array contains of DOM elements and not jquery objects, [0] is needed)
    var int = thresholds[++score]; //increase the score and check if interval should be increased for the new score
    if(int && int < interval){ 
     //optional: some message or css that interval is increased
     interval =int;
    }
    $("#scorecontainer").text(score);
  }
  
  this.pipe.click(backInGame.bind(this)); //bind the click
  this.timer =setTimeout(checkBurst.bind(this), 3000);
}
```

```css
@keyframes shake {
  5%,
  15%,
  25%,
  35%,
  45%,
  55%,
  65%,
  75%,
  85%,
  95% {
    left: 0;
    right: 1vh;
    outline: none;
    border-color: red;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px red;
  }
  10%,
  20%,
  30%,
  40%,
  50%,
  60%,
  70%,
  80%,
  90%,
  100% {
    left: 1vh;
    right: 0;
    outline: none;
    border-color: red;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px red;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes shake {
  5%,
  15%,
  25%,
  35%,
  45%,
  55%,
  65%,
  75%,
  85%,
  95% {
    left: 0;
    right: 1vh;
    outline: none;
    border-color: red;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px red;
  }
  10%,
  20%,
  30%,
  40%,
  50%,
  60%,
  70%,
  80%,
  90%,
  100% {
    left: 1vh;
    right: 0;
    outline: none;
    border-color: red;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px red;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes shake {
  5%,
  15%,
  25%,
  35%,
  45%,
  55%,
  65%,
  75%,
  85%,
  95% {
    left: 0;
    right: 1vh;
    outline: none;
    border-color: red;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px red;
  }
  10%,
  20%,
  30%,
  40%,
  50%,
  60%,
  70%,
  80%,
  90%,
  100% {
    left: 1vh;
    right: 0;
    outline: none;
    border-color: red;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px red;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes shake {
  5%,
  15%,
  25%,
  35%,
  45%,
  55%,
  65%,
  75%,
  85%,
  95% {
    left: 0;
    right: 1vh;
    outline: none;
    border-color: red;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px red;
  }
  10%,
  20%,
  30%,
  40%,
  50%,
  60%,
  70%,
  80%,
  90%,
  100% {
    left: 1vh;
    right: 0;
    outline: none;
    border-color: red;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px red;
  }
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#gamecontainer {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #49c1e2;
}

#gameinformation {
  height: 10%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 10%;
}

#pipecontainer {
  height: 80%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.pipe {
  height: 8vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: #a5a5a5;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.hitpoint {
  height: 10vh;
  width: 10vh;
  background-color: #6d6d6d;
  border-radius: 2vh;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 1vh;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#scoretext {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 6vh;
}

#scorecontainer {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 6vh;
}

#statusupdate {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 6vh;
}

.burstingpipe {
  animation-name: shake;
  animation-duration: 3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="gamecontainer">
  <div id="gameinformation">
    <p id="scoretext">Score:&nbsp;</p>
    <div id="scorecontainer">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="pipecontainer">
    <div class="pipe">
      <div class="hitpoint"></div>
      <div class="hitpoint"></div>
      <div class="hitpoint"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="pipe">
      <div class="hitpoint"></div>
      <div class="hitpoint"></div>
      <div class="hitpoint"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="pipe">
      <div class="hitpoint"></div>
      <div class="hitpoint"></div>
      <div class="hitpoint"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="statusupdate">
    <p id="result"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for taking the time in finding a solution to my problem! I found a different solution to give each individual pipe a unique timeout, this was by storing the timeout in a dynamic variable (created by using two variables) "pipe" + the pipes unique number. This way i could clear the individual timeouts as the pipes were clicked. The way you have done it looks much cleaner however and uses less code, so I may have to refactor my solution!

I'm also glad you enjoyed my game :), once again thank you for taking the time to provide a solution.

Answer (score 3):

I liked your game :)

And here is your problem: when the score increase, your are decreasing the timeout interval to have multiple shacked zone at the same time. And to stop all timer if the user loose, you are using this line:

> timeoutfunc = setTimeout(startaburst, interval);

and then

> clearTimeout(timeoutfunc);

This won't work because `timeoutfunc` will only contain the last launched Timeout and not all launched timeout (remember, while the check is done each 3 sec, the shaking timeout will run multiple times). So you need an array to keep all intervals and then clear all off them.

I updated your fiddle (also removed some unneeded lines)

```
var score = 0;
var numberofpipes = 9;
var lastnum = 0;
var intervalseconds;
var interval;
var haslost = false;
var checkpipetimer;
var timeoutfunc = [];
var timers = [];
var burstingpipes = {};
setTimeout(startaburst, 3000);
$('#scorecontainer').text(score);
//starts a bursting pipe
function startaburst() {
  if (score < 10) {
    intervalseconds = 2;
  } else if (score >= 10 && score < 25) {
    intervalseconds = 1.5;
  } else if (score >= 25 && score < 40) {
    intervalseconds = 1;
  } else if (score >= 40 && score < 60) {
    intervalseconds = 0.5;
  } else if (score >= 60) {
    intervalseconds = 0.25;
  } else if (score > 100) {
    intervalseconds = 0.1;
  }
  interval = intervalseconds * 1000;
  burstingpipe();
  //creating a loop with the new timeout value as the game gets harder.
  //also assigning it to the timeoutfunc variable so i can cancel the loop later.

  timeoutfunc.push(setTimeout(startaburst, interval));
}

//adds the bursting pipe attributes to the pipe intersections
function burstingpipe() {
  randomnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;
  //cant be the same twice in case of overlapping
  if ((randomnum == lastnum) || $("." + randomnum).hasClass("burstingpipe")) {
    //if the random num is still valid after -1, -1
    if (((randomnum - 1) >= 0) && !($("." + (randomnum - 1)).hasClass("burstingpipe"))) {
      randomnum = (randomnum - 1);
      //add one to the random number
    } else if (((randomnum + 1) <= (numberofpipes)) && !($("." + (randomnum + 1)).hasClass("burstingpipe"))) {
      randomnum = (randomnum + 1);
    } else {
      burstingpipe();
    }
  }
  //make the lastnum the current number so we dont get 2 in a row
  lastnum = randomnum;
  randomdiv = $("." + randomnum);
  console.log(randomdiv.hasClass("burstingpipe"));
  //adds shake animation and red glow
  console.log(randomnum);
  randomdiv.addClass("burstingpipe");

  //setting a timeout of 3 seconds, so th user has 3 seconds to press each 
  //bursting pipe before it bursts.
  checkpipetimer = setTimeout(haspipeburst.bind(this, randomdiv), 3000);
}

//function to check if the pipe has burst.
function haspipeburst(pipecheck) {
  console.log(pipecheck);
  console.log(pipecheck.hasClass("burstingpipe"));
  //checking to see if the pipe still has the class attached after 3 seconds
  //and if the user has already lost.
  if (pipecheck.hasClass("burstingpipe")) {
    //if the pipe still has the class attached - game over.
    haslost = true;
    $("#result").text("you have lost");
    //stopping the loop.
    for (var i = timeoutfunc.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
       clearTimeout(timeoutfunc[i]);
    }
    //changing the background color to make it look like the pipe has broken.
    //(will possibly change to image in future)
    //$(".hitpoint").removeClass("burstingpipe");
    $(pipecheck).css("background-color", "#49c1e2");
  }
}

//when the user clicks a hitpoint the class is removed and they gain a point.
$(document).on('click', '.hitpoint', function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass("burstingpipe") && haslost == false) {
    $(this).removeClass("burstingpipe");
    score++;
    $("#scorecontainer").text(score);
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi, Thankyou for taking a look! but it appears the problem still persists, would that be because my second timeout function in the bursting pipe function also needs to be stored as an array ?

Comment: looks like adding the second lot of timers to an array has fixed it ! thank-you for your help !!!!!